# Smack, Getting Error in creating new MultiChat

Tags: android, smack, asmack

I am using asmack for creating a chat app.
For creating a MultiUserChat i am using following code.

```
muc= new MultiUserChat(HomeActivity.connection, "chatRoom@conference.live-images.com");
        try 
        {
            muc.create(HomeActivity.connection.getUser());
            muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));


               muc.join("kam");
        } 
        catch (XMPPException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But i an getting the error.

Class CastException. & if i remove the Confrence from new MUC() then I get
Server Not Responsing Error.

Where i am wrong? Do i have to use some Patch.

Comment: Try posting the actual error.  You said you get a ClassCastException but not what it is on.  They are usually self explanatory, so the stacktrace would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be better to send more details like the stack trace.
Make sure you follow the code example here:
[Multi User Chat](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/extensions/muc.html)

Comment: DO you implemented multi user chat with private room?